# Getting valid values from ScrollInfo of a ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox, the issue I'm facing is trying to get valid values from the `IScrollInfo` object.

I know from setting MaxHeight on the ListBox to 150 that the ViewportHeight should be around this size and the full height is twice as big so the ExtentHeight should be about 300.

I get the following values from:
`_scrollInfo.ExtentHeight = 13`
`_scrollInfo.ViewportHeight = 7`
`_scrollInfo.VerticalOffset = varying but 1-6`

The values from:
`UIElement scrollable = _scrollInfo as UIElement;`
seem to be correct.
`scrollable.RenderSize.Height = 146` which is roughly right.

What I'm wondering about is:

When my ListBox control is first loaded it is bound to an empty `ObservableCollection`. It is not until later that items are added. Could it be that the IScrollInfo object is retaining these initial values from when the ListBox was empty?

The other thing the IScrollInfo object is a `VirtualizingStackPanel` could this have any bearing on the matter?

[EDIT]
Have tried changing the `VirtualizingStackPanel` to `StackPanel`, however I am still getting the same results.

Comment: `VirtualizingStackPanel` is usually a good culprit. It should be simple for you to check simply by making it a different container.

What exactly are you trying to use this information for?

Comment: I load up my ObservableCollection with CheckedListItem's which hold whether a DataGridColumn is visible or not. Through drag drop operations the columns can also be reordered. I have also added the ability to auto-scroll the ListBox while dragging. It is the auto-scroll that uses this information

Comment: When you say `simply by making it a different container` do you mean by creating a new control template for the ListBox?

Comment: By `make it a different container`, i mean replace the `VirtualizingStackPanel` with a stackpanel, or something else. See if you see the same behavior.

In regards to automating scrolling, you may want to try using an [`AutomationPeer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.peers.automationpeer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). I've used it before when I had to synchronize two scrollbars to each other.

Comment: Yes I get replacing the VirtualizingStackPanel with a StackPanel, but how? The actual auto-scroll works fine, but I will check out the alternative thanks. I'm actually using the vertical information for the dragged adorner.

Comment: Yes, you would have to replace the template. You can find the existing ones on MSDN or pull it out of blend.

Comment: Do you happen to know why the VirtualizingStackPanel has the issue in the first place?

Comment: Well, i don't know specifically that it is your issue, but I know that myself and other co-workers have run into issues with it before. 
Full disclosure, our software is on silverlight, not WPF. The WPF version could be flawless.

Comment: Quick update: Replaced the VirtualizingStackPanel with a StackPanel, unfortunately I am getting the same results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This behaviour is given by `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"`
It basically says, that you are not allowed to scroll by pixels, but only by items.

Consider this example:

```
private void ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged(object sender, ScrollChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var scrollViewer = (ScrollViewer) sender;
    Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("ExtentHeight: {0}, ViewportHeight : {1}, VerticalOffset : {2}",
        scrollViewer.ExtentHeight, scrollViewer.ViewportHeight, scrollViewer.VerticalOffset));
}


<ScrollViewer Height="150" ScrollChanged="ScrollViewer_ScrollChanged" CanContentScroll="True">
    <VirtualizingStackPanel>
        <Rectangle Height="40" Margin="5" Fill="Red" />
        <Rectangle Height="40" Margin="5" Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Height="40" Margin="5" Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Height="40" Margin="5" Fill="Red" />
        <Rectangle Height="40" Margin="5" Fill="Green" />
        <Rectangle Height="40" Margin="5" Fill="Blue" />
        <Rectangle Height="40" Margin="5" Fill="Red" />
    </VirtualizingStackPanel>
</ScrollViewer>
```

you get following output:

```
ExtentHeight: 7, ViewportHeight : 3, VerticalOffset : 0   
ExtentHeight: 7, ViewportHeight : 3, VerticalOffset : 1
ExtentHeight: 7, ViewportHeight : 3, VerticalOffset : 2
```

but when you set `CanContentScroll="False"`:

```
ExtentHeight: 350, ViewportHeight : 150, VerticalOffset : 3,01724137931035
ExtentHeight: 350, ViewportHeight : 150, VerticalOffset : 6,03448275862069
ExtentHeight: 350, ViewportHeight : 150, VerticalOffset : 9,05172413793104
ExtentHeight: 350, ViewportHeight : 150, VerticalOffset : 12,0689655172414
ExtentHeight: 350, ViewportHeight : 150, VerticalOffset : 15,0862068965517
ExtentHeight: 350, ViewportHeight : 150, VerticalOffset : 18,1034482758621
ExtentHeight: 350, ViewportHeight : 150, VerticalOffset : 21,1206896551724
```

In the first example you are scrolling by items. You have seven items, so ExtentHeight is 7 and 3 items are visible, so ViewportHeight is 3.

In the second example you are scrolling by pixels, so ExtentHeight is total height of all items and viewport height is height of scrollviewver

Moral of the story is, that in some scenarios you dont want to measure size of all items, because it could have negative performance effect. It's the case especially when virtualizing elements.

Comment: Couldn't ask for a better explaination! Thank you.